# Убрать горизонтальную прокрутку, на мобильной версии сайта

Tags: html, css

Как убрать горизонтальную прокрутку сайта в мобильной версии? Один элемент (позиционированный абсолютно) при уменьшении ширины сайта, оставляет белую полосу справа (дизайнером задумано чтобы он выходил за рамки).
Если прописать overflow родительскому элементу, то сразу обрезается низ элемента (айфон).
Думал может весь сайт (после body), обернуть в див с overflow: hidden?
Как правильно поступить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Можно через overflow-x: hidden

Comment: Не работает(. Все равно внизу тогда обрезается айфон

Comment: Не совсем понятно тогда, есть где-то исходный код? Что бы подробнее посмотреть

Comment: отправьте проект или его кусок, так будет проще нам решить вашу проблему